# MultiBind string resources with StringFormat

Tags: c#, wpf, multibinding, staticresource

I'm trying to multi-bind a formattable string from my localized resources in a TextBlock.

The string looks as following:
`This record is locked for edit by {0}.`

Now I want to bind that to a TextBlock:

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}">
            <Binding Source="{x:Static res:LocalizedResources.EntityLockedMessageTitleFormat}" />
            <Binding Path="Entity.LockedBy" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

But unfortunately, this only shows the actual string (containing the {0}).

How can I multi bind this? Most desirably without the use of converters (purely in XAML).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just think of the initial `{}` being the start of the `StringFormat`. Then each `Binding` value can be accessed using the next consecutive index. Try this:

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} {1}.">
            <Binding Source="{x:Static res:LocalizedResources.EntityLockedMessageTitleFormat}" />
            <Binding Path="Entity.LockedBy" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

When confused about a .NET class or function, it is usually best to go to MSDN, where you can normally find a detailed explanation and code example. Please see the [MultiBinding Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN for further information on using `MultiBinding`s.

---

UPDATE >>>

You cannot use a `string` like `Entity {0} is locked by {1} since {2}.` as a format `string` in XAML. Instead, what you *could* do is to format the `string` in code and expose the result as a property that you could data bind to in the UI. Try something like this:

```
public string FormattedString
{
    get { return string.Format(YourEntityLockedMessageTitleFormat, Val1, Val2, Val3); }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately, this results in the following output (John Doe being the Entity.LockedBy): `This record is locked for edit by {0}. John Doe`

Comment: Ok, now I see what you mean about your `EntityLockedMessageTitleFormat` value... you can't use it like that. That value *should* be: '`This record is locked for edit by`' *without* the '`{0}.`'.

Comment: So, when adding a second parameter, for example a date, this is still unusable? For example I can't add the following string to my resources? `Entity {0} is locked by {1} since {2}`. That wouldn't allow me to concatenate (aswell as being ugly for other languages)?

Comment: Thanks, I'll go for your "FormattedString" suggestion. Appreciated!