# Label Multibinding With Static

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

How can I display a `x:Static` variable in a `MultiBinding` `Label`?

```
<Label>
    <Label.Text>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} {1}">
            <Binding Path="x:Static resources:AppResources.FirstName"/>
            <Binding Path="User.FirstName"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </Label.Text>
</Label>
```

Desired result:

> First Name: John

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25160189/multibind-string-resources-with-stringformat, or put {0} into resource.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Path`, use `Source`.

```
<Label>
    <Label.Text>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} {1}">
            <Binding Source="{x:Static resources:AppResources.FirstName}"/>
            <Binding Path="User.FirstName"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </Label.Text>
</Label>
```